# Instaling Orchard at the root stops other ASP.net applications at different folders

Tags: orchardcms

After installing Orchard by using Webmatrix at the root my other applications stop. What could be the reason and how I can make other applications in a working condition.

Thanks to all.

Edit: Showing
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you sure they actually are IIS web applications? I have a site where Orchard is at the root and another unrelated application runs in a folder, without a problem.

Another thing to check is web.config. Because Orchard is above and has a pretty restrictive config, you may have to restore some settings in the sub-dirs.

Comment: Yes, they are web apps. Before installing Orchard at the root, they worked perfectly but now gives,Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Yeah, check your web.config files then.

Comment: Other apps in different folder are not MVC apps.

Comment: It doesn't matter, they still have a web.config that will get affected by what's above.

Comment: I have added   <assemblies>
        <remove assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" /> but still not working

Comment: mmh, why are you *removing* assemblies? You should be looking at what Orchard's config is removing, and restoring that. You might need to compare with the machine.config.

Comment: Because I am not using Mvc in other apps, only in the root.So far I have found that root's web.config value propagate to it's children. And to protect this, I have wrapped <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> around <system.web> and <system.webServer>

Comment: Please provide the reason for downvoting, it might help others to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

> Answering own question and marked it
>   as answer
>   I feel uneasy. Anyway after--

Adding  on the top of  and close the location tag at the end of  solved my problem.

Here is the web.config file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>

    <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor">
        <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
      </sectionGroup>
      <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
      <add key="log4net.Config" value="Config\log4net.config" />
    </appSettings>

    <system.web.webPages.razor>
      <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <pages pageBaseType="Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.Razor.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
          <add namespace="System.Linq" />
          <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
          <add namespace="Orchard.Mvc.Html" />
        </namespaces>
      </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>
    <!-- 
        Set default transaction timeout to 30 minutes so that interactive debugging 
        is easier (default timeout is less than one minute)
  -->
    <system.transactions>
      <defaultSettings timeout="00:30:00" />
    </system.transactions>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <!--<trust level="Medium" originUrl="" />-->
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
      <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
    -->
      <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" batch="true" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="250">
        <buildProviders>
          <add extension=".csproj" type="Orchard.Environment.Extensions.Compilers.CSharpExtensionBuildProviderShim" />
        </buildProviders>
        <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
          <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
          <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
          <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
          <remove assembly="System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
          <remove assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
          <remove assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          <remove assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
          <remove assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          <remove assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
          <remove assembly="System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
          <remove assembly="System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          <remove assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          <remove assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          <remove assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <remove assembly="System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <remove assembly="System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <remove assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <remove assembly="System.WorkflowServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <remove assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <remove assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          <remove assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </assemblies>
      </compilation>
      <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Users/Account/AccessDenied" timeout="2880" />
      </authentication>
      <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.
    -->
      <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
      <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
        <namespaces>
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
          <add namespace="System.Linq" />
          <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
          <add namespace="Orchard.Mvc.Html" />
        </namespaces>
      </pages>
      <httpHandlers>
        <!-- see below -->
        <clear />
        <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <httpModules>
        <add name="WarmupHttpModule" type="Orchard.WarmupStarter.WarmupHttpModule, Orchard.WarmupStarter, Version=1.0.20, Culture=neutral" />
      </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
  -->
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="WarmupHttpModule" />
        <add name="WarmupHttpModule" type="Orchard.WarmupStarter.WarmupHttpModule, Orchard.WarmupStarter, Version=1.0.20, Culture=neutral" />
      </modules>
      <handlers accessPolicy="Script">
        <!-- clear all handlers, prevents executing code file extensions, prevents returning any file contents -->
        <clear />
        <!-- Return 404 for all requests via managed handler. The url routing handler will substitute the mvc request handler when routes match. -->
        <add name="NotFound" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" requireAccess="Script" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    </location>
    <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <probing privatePath="App_Data/Dependencies" />
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <system.data>
      <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
        <add invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" name="Microsoft® SQL Server® Compact 4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Please provide the reason for downvoting, it might help others to understand. Thanks.