# ASP.NET MVC3 ignore route in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, subdomain, orchardcms, subdirectory

I'm new to Orchard CMS and currently playing with it, trying to build new site.
Besides that I have several test sites (on PHP and static html) that reside on the same hosting server in sub-directories, e.g "mysite.com/test_site". 
The Orchard resides in the root directory and intercepts all requests
It just dies with unhandled exception when accessing PHP site:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Orchard.WarmupStarter, Version=1.0.20, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

When trying to access static html site ASP.NET returns 404:

```
The resource cannot be found.
```

I tried suggested solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541716/instaling-orchard-at-the-root-stops-other-asp-net-applications-at-different-fold). But adding location tag blocks all the CSS/images/scripts on main site, so it looks like plain text on white background.
I thought it will be good idea just to add ignore routes in Global.asax.cs, like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("test_site/{*pathInfo}");
}
```

However, there is no Global.asax.cs in Orchard site.
Any ideas where to find routes in Orchard to try this? Or any other solution to make sub-directories to be ignored and path through the request to be handled by IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If modifying the config removed access to your styles, that just means that you did not apply the change locally enough. Please read this thread for more info on making this work: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/264057

Comment: Thanks for reply! Do you mean I have to copy/paste sections <system.web> and <system.webServer> for each Orchard folder and wrap them in location tag, like this:
    
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.web /> 
        <system.webServer />
    </location>
    <location path="Media" inheritInChildApplications="true">
        <system.web /> 
        <system.webServer />
    </location>
    
Is there more elegant solution? :)

Comment: No, quite the reverse actually: it's your new virtual diretory that should have its own specific loation-based config so as not to affect the rest of the application. You should also already have a web.config file in every folder that serves static resources.

Comment: You mean I have to put web.config in test site folder? Will it solve the problem if it's PHP and/or static site?